# Centred vertical line between two divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following layout (except with a straight line obviously)

[image]

But I'm unsure how to, I tried adding a right border to the left element, but it isn't centred. How do I go about it?

This is what I have at the moment

```css
 div.contentswrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 720px;
 }

div.pageleft, div.pageright {
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 overflow: auto;
 }

 div.pageleft, div.pageright {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="contentswrapper">
 
  <div class="pageleft">
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <p>
   </p>
   <p>
   </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pageright">
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <p>
   </p>
   <p>
   </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your margins to paddings, and then set the border

```css
div.contentswrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 720px;
}
div.pageleft,
div.pageright {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.pageleft,
div.pageright {
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
div.pageleft {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentswrapper">

  <div class="pageleft">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="pageright">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Option 2, use a pseudo element and its border

```css
div.contentswrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 720px;
}
div.contentswrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 2px);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
div.pageleft,
div.pageright {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.pageleft,
div.pageright {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentswrapper">

  <div class="pageleft">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="pageright">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need to use `inline-block`, you can just float them and set the right border of the left `div`.

Changing the margin settings to paddings instead will correct the slight center misalignment because your total widths don't add up to a perfect 100%.

Also, you don't need 2 style rules with the same selectors, you can combine them.

```css
div.contentswrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 720px;
 }

.pageleft { border-right:2px solid black;}

div.pageleft, div.pageright {
  float:left;
 vertical-align: top;
  width: 42%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="contentswrapper">
 
  <div class="pageleft">
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <p>sdfff</p>
   <p>sdfsdfsd</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pageright">
   <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
   <p>sdfff</p>
   <p>sdfsdfsd</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: That isn't centered... The OP said he already tried this, and wanted it centered.